# css and html problem "How I can add a close tab In my design"

Tags: html, css

I was working on a custom design  On WordPress website ,
But I'm stuck in a problem and I don't know how to solve it.

The end result is supposed to be like this :

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrS5E.jpg)

but I am getting this result  In my end :

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYP6g.png)

The problem is that the closing (x) does not appear.

code :

```css
/* Pop Up Animation Ramadan */

@keyframes flipInX {
    from {
        transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 90deg);
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;
        opacity: 0
    }
    40% {
        transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -20deg);
        animation-timing-function: ease-in
    }
    60% {
        transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, 10deg);
        opacity: 1
    }
    80% {
        transform: perspective(400px) rotate3d(1, 0, 0, -5deg)
    }
    to {
        transform: perspective(400px)
    }
}

@keyframes change_color {
    0% {
        background: #5ac7da
    }
    33.33% {
        background: #3173bd
    }
    66.66% {
        background: #0d4a8d
    }
    100% {
        background: #5ac7da
    }
}

@keyframes run_hari18 {
    0% {
        transform: translate(0%, 0);
        opacity: 0
    }
    50% {
        transform: translate(100%, 0);
        opacity: 1
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(100%, 0);
        opacity: 0
    }
}

@keyframes sun_movement {
    0% {
        top: 50px
    }
    100% {
        top: 50px
    }
}

@keyframes run_malam18 {
    0% {
        transform: translate(-20%, 0);
        opacity: 0
    }
    49.99% {
        transform: translate(0%, 0);
        opacity: 1
    }
    99.99% {
        transform: translate(20%, 0);
        opacity: 0
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(-20%, 0);
        opacity: 1
    }
}

@keyframes moon_movement {
    0% {
        transform: translate(-200%, 0);
        opacity: 0
    }
    49.99% {
        transform: translate(0%, 0);
        opacity: 1
    }
    99.99% {
        transform: translate(200%, 0);
        opacity: 0
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate(-200%, 0);
        opacity: 1
    }
}


/*custom*/

#arlinapuasa2018 {
    display: block;
    background: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    top: 25%;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 660px;
    box-shadow: 0 19px 38px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 0 15px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    z-index: 99;
    min-height: 350px;
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
    animation: change_color 7s infinite linear, flipInX 1s linear
}

#arlinapuasa2018 .puasa18 {
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding: 30px;
    z-index: 99999;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 20%
}

#arlinapuasa2018 .puasa18 p {
    margin: 20px auto 20px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)
}

#arlinapuasa2018 .puasa18 .ramadan2018 {
    font-size: 3rem;
    font-weight: 700
}

#arlinapuasa2018 a.close-popup {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1px;
    right: 1px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 999999;
    transition: all .3s
}

#arlinapuasa2018 a.close-popup:hover {
    color: #fff
}

#arlinapuasa2018 a.close-popup:active {
    opacity: 0
}

#arlinapuasa2018 a.close-popup i {
    font-family: fontawesome;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    transform: rotate(270deg);
    transition: all .3s
}

#arlinapuasa2018 a.close-popup:hover i {
    transform: rotate(360deg)
}

.gunung18 {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    display: block;
    background: #4aad52;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -150px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    border-radius: 50px;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 0;
}

.gunung18.behind {
    background: #42a54a;
    right: -120px;
    bottom: -180px;
    z-index: 1
}

.hari18 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    animation: run_hari18 7s infinite linear
}

.hari18 .awan18 {
    margin: 30px auto;
    width: 150px;
    height: 70px;
    display: block;
    background: #e7e7e7;
    border-radius: 35px;
    border: 10px solid #ffffff;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -7px 0 0 #d7d7d7;
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px;
    left: 50px
}

.hari18 .awan18:before {
    content: ''', ''';
    width: 65px;
    height: 35px;
    display: block;
    background: #e7e7e7;
    border-radius: 35px 35px 0 0;
    border: 10px solid #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: -35px;
    left: 20px
}

.hari18 .awan18.invert {
    top: 60px;
    left: 250px
}

.hari18 .awan18.invert:before {
    left: 50px
}

.hari18 .sun {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    display: block;
    background: #fff297;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: inset -5px -5px 0 0 #ddc991;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 0;
    animation: sun_movement 7s infinite linear
}

.malam18 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    animation: run_malam18 7s infinite linear
}

.malam18 .bintang18 .star {
    width: 5px;
    height: 5px;
    display: block;
    background: #f7f7f7;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute
}

.malam18 .bintang18 .star:nth-child(1) {
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px
}

.malam18 .bintang18 .star:nth-child(2) {
    top: 200px;
    left: 70px
}

.malam18 .bintang18 .star:nth-child(3) {
    top: 100px;
    left: 300px
}

.malam18 .bintang18 .star:nth-child(4) {
    top: 50px;
    left: 220px
}

.malam18 .bintang18 .star:nth-child(5) {
    top: 160px;
    left: 320px
}

.malam18 .bintang18 .star:nth-child(6) {
    top: 150px;
    left: 230px
}

.malam18 .bintang18 .star:nth-child(7) {
    top: 180px;
    left: 400px
}

.malam18 .bintang18 .star:nth-child(8) {
    top: 50px;
    left: 360px
}

.malam18 .moon {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    display: block;
    background: #d7d7d7;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: inset -5px -5px 0 0 #c7c7c7;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 100px;
    animation: moon_movement 7s infinite linear
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css">
<!-- Start Ramdan -->
    <div id='arlinapuasa2018'>
    <div class="overflow-hid">
            <div class='puasa18'>
            <p>كل عام والأمة الأسلامية بخير</p>
            <p><span class='ramadan2018'>رمضان كريم</span></p>
        </div>
            <div class='gunung18'></div>
            <div class='gunung18 behind'></div>
        <div class='hari18'>
            <div class='awan18'></div>
            <div class='awan18 invert'></div>
            <div class='sun'></div>
        </div>
        <div class='malam18'>
            <div class='bintang18'>
                <div class='star'></div>
                <div class='star'></div>
                <div class='star'></div>
                <div class='star'></div>
                <div class='star'></div>
                <div class='star'></div>
                <div class='star'></div>
                <div class='star'></div>
            </div>
            <div class='moon'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
   <a class='close-popup' href='#' title='close'><i class='fa fa-times'></i></a>
</div>
<!-- End Ramdan -->

<!--  ramdan js -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
//<![CDATA[
// Ramadan
jQuery(function($) {
    $(window).bind("load",function(){
        $("#arlinapuasa2018").animate({top:"15%"},1e3),
        $("a.close-popup").click(function(){
            return $(this).parent().fadeOut(2e3),!2;
        })
    });
}); 

</script>
```

I hope someone here can help me with that .
I just want to be able to cloes tap In this  design

Comment: Hello, I don't anything can help me !

Answer (score 0):

You can add

```js
    $("#close-popup").click(function() {
        $("#arlinapuasa2018").remove();
    })
```

to your code.

and if you don't see the X check if your fontawesome tag works or just replace:

```html
<a class='close-popup' href='#' title='close'><i class='fa fa-times'></i></a>`
```

with

```html
<a class='close-popup' href='#' title='close'>X</a>`
```

Or add `z-index: 1000;` on `#close-popup` to put in the foreground.

Comment: Thank you for tha awnser . But it didn't work for me. your code `<a class='close-popup' href='#' title='close'>X</a>` work but I want the original one .

Comment: Hello , I want to close the tap without the jQuery.